# Creating a row of numbers/ letters in my Python Battleship game

Tags: python

I am trying to get my grid to display like this:

```
 1 2 3 4   
A- - - -  
B- - - -  
C- - - -  
D- - - -
```

I have tried various ways of attempting this but I cannot seem to get it working. Would anyone have any suggestions?

Also in my login the while loop seems to be stuck. I put in a break a few times but again cant seem to get it working correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
from random import randint
import getpass

users = {}
status = ""

def displayMenu():
    status = input("Are you registered user? y/n? ")
    if status == "y":
        oldUser()
    elif status == "n":
        newUser()

def newUser():
    createLogin = input("Create login name: ")

    if createLogin in users:
        print("\nLogin name already exist!\n")
    else:
         createPassw = input("Create password: ")
            users[createLogin] = createPassw
        print("\nUser created\n")

def oldUser():
    login = input("Enter login name: ")
    passw = input("Enter password: ")

    if login in users and users[login] == passw:
        print("\nLogin successful!\n")
    else:
        print("\nUser doesn't exist or wrong password!\n")

while status != "q":
   displayMenu() #cant stop the loop here


board = []
#building the gameboard
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["-"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print((" ").join(row))

print("Let's play Battleship!")
print("Find and sink the ship!")
print_board(board)

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)
def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

ship_row = random_row(board)
ship_col = random_col(board)

for turn in range(9):
    print ("Turn"), turn
    guess_row = int(input("Guess Row:"))
    guess_col = int(
        input("Guess Col:"))

    if guess_row == ship_row and guess_col == ship_col:
        print("Congratulations! You sunk my battleship!")
        break
    else:
        if (guess_row < 0 or guess_row > 5) or (guess_col < 0 or guess_col > 5):
            print("Oops, that's not even in the ocean.")
        elif(board[guess_row][guess_col] == "X"):
            print("You guessed that one already.")
        else:
            print("You missed my battleship!")
            board[guess_row][guess_col] = "X"
    if turn == 8:
        print("Game Over")
    turn =+ 1
    print_board(board)
```

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow should have a single question. That makes them more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to print your board with column numbers and row letters. We can use `.join` to print the column headers, just like you print the row data. And we can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to loop over the row letters & row data in parallel.

```
# Building the gameboard
board = []
for x in range(5):
    board.append(["-"] * 5)

def print_board(board):
    print(" ", " ".join("12345"))
    for letter, row in zip("ABCDE", board):
        print(letter, " ".join(row))

print_board(board)
```

**output**

```
  1 2 3 4 5
A - - - - -
B - - - - -
C - - - - -
D - - - - -
E - - - - -
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that!!

Comment: @AoifeEllenRyan And you should separate the stuff out about the password loop and ask a fresh question. Although at this stage, that password stuff doesn't do much, since your program doesn't save the passwords on disk, and you only allow the user to play a single game.

Comment: im working on adding sqlite at the minute to save the data. Hoping to add a win counter and highscore function also! This is only my first python project so struggling big time! Thanks so much for the help!